# Only have Firefox extension code run once per session

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am creating a Firefox extension that requires the user to login.  Each time a new window, but not new tab is opened, the 'code' for the extension is run.  I would prefer that the code is only run one time per session.

The setup of the extension looks like this.  (let me know if I am missing anything):

in chrome manifest:
`overlay    chrome://browser/content/browser.xul  chrome://my/overlay.xul`

in overlay.xul:
`<overlay id="socialSidebarOverlay" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">`
`<script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://my/code.js" />`
`</overlay>`

in code.js:
`alert('being called')`

The problem is that "being called" should only be displayed when Firefox starts up, not when new tabs or windows are opened.  What would be a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [JavaScript code module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_code_modules/Using) to make sure your code is only executed once.

Comment: Thank you!!!! This is exactly what I was looking for.  The JSM module is only loaded once even after tabs and new windows are opened :)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to observe (and act on) one of the possible [Mozilla Observer Notifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Observer_Notifications)

Either actually act on something when starting up, or in you extension check for a particular value that is reset when the browser closes [this can be tricky, as abnormal shutdowns may not reset].

See Also: [Receiving Startup Notifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM/Receiving_startup_notifications)